# Nunca usar estilos inline é nunca mesmo?

Tags: html, css, estilo-de-codificação

Por exemplo a *tag* `canvas`:

Vi alguns tutoriais no YouTube, e em quase todos eles usavam assim:

```
<canvas height="" width=""></canvas>.
```

Então devo usar no HTML, *inline*, como acima, ou como no exemplo abaixo, no CSS?

```
canvas {
    height: ;
    width: ;
}
```

Existe alguma diferença na prática?

Comment: É importante notar que, quando se inspeciona o HTML em uma página, você está vendo a versão final, mastigada, do que foi originalmente escrito de forma que "fique simples para o browser entender". Pode ser que no HTML original esses estilos nunca foram escritos, e na verdade injetados por um *framework* como jQuery, por exemplo. Com as várias ferramentas hoje disponíveis pode-se manter os fontes bem enxutos e documentados (aderindo às *"boas práticas"*) ainda gerando código capaz de manter a compatibilidade através de diferentes sistemas/navegadores.

Comment: **Possível** duplicata de [Por que a Google recomenda CSS inline?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214425/por-que-a-google-recomenda-css-inline)

Comment: Seria bom definir melhor se o assunto é usar CSS inline, ou se é o fato de omitir os valores; no meu ver, a resposta aceita fala de um assunto que nada tem a ver com o título da pergunta, que é "Nunca usar estilos inline é nunca mesmo?" - convém um pouco mais de especificidade quando for abrir novas questões..

Comment: eu pensei em mudar o titulo mas dai ja tinham respondido, dai acabei deixando.

Answer (score 14):

Se algo existe e não é declarado como total legado e que há problemas, sempre pode usar qualquer coisa no contexto certo, se souber o que está fazendo.

O que está sendo falado é uma variação do que se chama "boas práticas". Como eu sempre respondo, isso foi criado para facilitar a passagem de conhecimento de quem já entende bem sobre algo para quem ainda não sabe. O problema é que começou acontecer de pessoas que não sabem bem sobre o assunto criar boas práticas ou disseminar as existentes sem se atentar aos detalhes, sabe, tipo um [telefone sem fio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telefone_sem_fio_(brincadeira))? Portanto criando *fake news*.

Então as pessoas pegam o resumo e disseminam a informação "pela metade". E as pessoas que consumem boas práticas se contentam com elas sem querer se aprofundar e entender do que se trata. A boa prática é boa como um *check list*. Ela não deve eliminar o aprofundamento que todos devem ter sobre o assunto.

Uma das boas práticas mais usadas é dizer "sempre faça isto", "nunca faça isto". A questão é que sem um contexto a boa prática perde o sentido. Sempre ou nunca é muito tempo, abrange situações demais. Sempre tem caso para usar de uma forma que não é a tradicional, a mais recomendada para boa parte dos casos.

Não tem nada de errado em fazer estilos *inline*. É claro que essa forma pode dificultar certas características que você pode desejar.

Quando faz *inline* complica para trocar o estilo, se for usar ele várias vezes perde o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e não é só questão da codificação, pode pesar na carga da página, pode dificultar a organização geral, se for uma equipe pode criar problemas de manutenção entre os membros, acaba dando uma responsabilidade múltipla para a página, só para citar algumas coisas.

Mas tem casos que você está fazendo algo mais simples ou tem uma funcionalidade específica que fica melhor o *inline*, então pode usar sim. A questão é saber o que está fazendo, entender as consequências de cada escolha, entender o seu problema e definir o que serve melhor ao propósito.

No caso do [`canvas` está na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) o uso desses atributos e nenhuma recomendação para não usá-lo. Pode usar se fizer sentido naquele contexto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

## Em websites

Deixar os estilos *inline* não te possibilita o **reuso de código**, que é bem importante na engenharia de software. Reaproveitar código (bem escrito) fará do seu tempo de desenvolvimento mais rápido e padronizado.

Supondo que você precise do mesmo estilo para usar em outro elemento na mesma ou em outra página, você precisaria reescrevê-lo, e se precisasse alterá-lo, precisaria alterar em todas as ocorrências em que você utilizou tal estilo. Esse problema poderia ter sido evitado se você tivesse uma folha de estilo em comum para todos esses elementos.

Existe um princípio do desenvolvimento de software chamado DRY (*Don't Repeat Yourself*) que fala justamente sobre o reuso de código. Tem [boas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120931/o-dry-%C3%A9-para-evitar-redund%C3%A2ncias-certo) sobre esse princípio aqui no site.

É claro que visualmente, sua página ficará igual, mas o tempo de desenvolvimento pode subir, você gastará mais tempo fazendo menos. Produtividade é bem importante quando se fala em software.

## Em e-mails

O submundo do desenvolvimento de e-mails com HTML e CSS, visando suporte em diferentes clientes, é complicado. O que o Gmail suporta, o Hotmail por vezes não, e não esquecer do app de e-mail do iOS, do Android, e outros clientes na conta!

Geralmente usa-se CSS inline em e-mails. Uma pesquisa do site Litmus mostra que 85.5% dos e-mails enviados por marketeiros *inlinearizam* seu CSS por questões de compatibilidade.

Existem inclusive ferramentas que pegam um arquivo HTML com CSS definido na tag `style` e transforma tudo em inline, para e-mails.

Comment: Eu nunca trabalhei com programacao, mas quantas linhas normalmente escrevem por dia os profissionais?

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta é bastante subjetiva. Muitas linhas de código podem até não ser uma coisa boa dependendo do contexto. Às vezes você pode escrever um código gigantesco, mas que seja quase ilegível para um outro desenvolvedor que tiver que dar manutenção no seu código, o contrário também pode ser válido. Tem vezes que a gente fica mais tempo lendo código do que escrevendo :P

Comment: Acredito que não tem como medir corretamente pois diferentes linguagem geram mais ou menos linhas e no fim depende de cada pessoa, mas se quiser ver  números (muitos) de uma olhada em projetos de github la mostra a quantidade de código escrita por cada pessoa

Comment: @ViniciusPuttiMorais Se você quiser ter uma noção, "em números", realmente varia da velocidade com que a pessoa digita e o quanto o trabalho dela resulta em precisar escrever código novo. Tem pessoas que "escrevem" facilmente mais de 10k linhas em um dia. Mas não necessariamente todos os dias. Muitas vezes pequenas alterações (coisa de 10-100 linhas) alteram completamente o comportamento de um programa/sistema. O que leva mais tempo nesse caso é a análise e o planejamento de como isso será feito. Isso é mais importante do que o a quantidade de linhas em qualquer cenário.

Answer (score 4):

Esse uso de deixar a tag canvas com width e height vazios provavelmente é para limpar os valores padrão que toda tag tem.

Já no caso do CSS, essa técnica também é utilizada e tem o nome comum de 'Reset CSS', o mais famoso é o [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Neste caso, o seu exemplo ficaria:

```
canvas {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Como você colocou no exemplo daria erro pois foge inclusive da sintaxe do CSS.